# unserialize arabic letters rendering ??? as output

Tags: php, serialization, utf-8, arabic

i have the following bit of code:

```
function appear($data)
{
    $output = '';
    $unsee = unserialize ( $data );
    if (is_array ( $nsee ))
    {
        $output .= '<table>' . "";
        foreach ( $nsee as $button )
        {
            $output .= loadbutton ( $button);
        }
        $output .= '
        <tr><td>IP</td>
        <td>' . $_SERVER ['REMOTE_ADDR'] . '</td></tr>' . "";
        $output .= '</table>' . "";
    }
    return $output;
}

function loadbutton($button)
{
    $output = '';
    $output .= '<tr>' . "";
    $output .= '<td>';
    $output .= $button ['values'];
    $output .= '</td><td>';
    $output .= $_POST [strtolower ( $button ['values'])] ;
    $output .= '</td>' . "";
    $output .= '</tr>' . "";
    return $output;
}
```

when i use the appear function for the english serialized data, it works perfectly and outputs fine.

But when i use it for the arabic serilaized data. everything works except the arabic letters appear as "????" and not as actual arabic letters.

I have verified the data in the database, everything is UTF-8, and everything is valid db wise and saving serilaized wise. but the output and unserialization is incorrect.

Do you know a way to fix this?
Does unserialization support arabic letters? if not then why does it save arabic letters correctly but not fetches them?

**EDIT:**

The problem i believe is in the call $button ['values'].

my `$button` array is 
`array ( 'values' => 'Field Value')`

no solution comes to mind. i know it should work.

**SOLUTION:**

The problem was in my mysql insert statement of the serialized data. i was inserting in latin. a simple, idiotic mistake.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does your HTML code have UTF-8 set as the page's character encoding?

Comment: In all files in my script, and in the database and in mysql connection. everything is utf-8. i have also tested removing `strtolower` with no change.

Comment: Can you possibly link us to the page?

Comment: its in development in localhost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you have set in your HTML document:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>`

or have it set using an HTTP header by placing this at the TOP of your PHP code BEFORE any content is output:

`header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

The browser is not using the correct character set, and is thus displaying `?` in place of those characters.

Also use:

```
$output .= $_POST[mb_strtolower($button['values'], 'UTF-8')];
```

As `strtolower()` will not properly lowercase multi-byte chars.

Comment: I have done so already. I believe i tracked the problem to the array pointer in my unserialize return array. the array in english is `array ( 'values' => 'Field Value')`  but in arabic it is `
array ( 'values' => 'قيمة حقل')` in the database. But when i call it in my php using `$button['values'];` it causes the error. no idea why, but its a problem in the array.

Comment: @AbdullahHasan You should use `mb_strtolower($button['values'], 'UTF-8')` as regular `strtolower()` will not properly lowercase.

Comment: I have done so, and also i have setted mb encoding to utf-8. no cigar.

Comment: I know the problem is not in my charset, because everything you mentioned i already have done. the problem is in the array call for sure. because calling the english value returns valid, but the arabic value returns signs.

Comment: @AbdullahHasan Because they are different character sets that is why. Can you please check your HTTP headers for the page and make sure the server is sending the correct HTTP header. Or at least try the above `header()` solution.

Comment: I have figured out the problem, i am so stupid. Thank you very much for your attempts to solve my mistake.

Comment: @AbdullahHasan, what was the problem?

Comment: Submitting serialized data as latin, but fetching it as utf-8.

Comment: omg, \*jumps off a cliff\*, well at least you got it fixed. =o)